# Cambiar <Title> con include

Tags: php

Tengo el título del sitio en un archivo aparte y lo he insertado con include, por lo tanto el titulo de todas las secciones de mi sitio son iguales. Hay alguna forma de aplicar uno distinto para cada sección? o la única manera sería sacar el  he ingresarlo manualmente uno por uno?

Comment: Recomiendo que agregues el codigo que lleves hasta el momento

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar que todas las secciones tengan el mismo título debes remplazar por variables `php`

**Me explicó**

Normalmente yo suelo dividir las páginas con **PHP** en 3/2 partes.

**1 -** Header donde incluyó ***(titulo, menú de navegación etc.)***

**2 -** Footer

Ahora desde la página **Index.php** u otra página, comienzo a llamar el Header y el Footer.

**Ejemplo:**

```
<?php
include "template/header.php";
?>

// Contenido de la página



<?php
include "template/footer.php";
?>
```

En la plantilla del **header.php** debes reemplazar el texto del `title` por una variable de PHP

**Ejemplo:**

```
<title><?php echo $title;?></title>
```

Ahora por encima del include del **header.php** crear el valor de la variable en este caso el título de la página.

```
$title = "Hola Mundo";
```

**Ejemplo completo**

```
<?php
 $title = "Hola Mundo";
?>

<?php
include "template/header.php";
?>

// Contenido de la página



<?php
include "template/footer.php";
?>
```

> Recuerda remplazar el texto común del `title` por las variables de **php**